# Why does my 2 way binding not work

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to bind 2 ways

In my ViewModel, I have

```
    private Temporary _selectedCompany;
    public Temporary SelectedCompany
    {
        get
        {
            return this._selectedCompany;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this._selectedCompany == value || value == null)
                return;

            this._selectedCompany = value;
            this.SelectedCompany.CompanyName = "TestName";
            base.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCompany");
        }
    }
```

`Temporary` is actually a class similar to a class you'd do for a CompanyAddress (name, country, phone etc) and was created by EntityFramework.

In the corresponding View, the XAML is

```
<local:CompanyDetail CompanyName="{Binding SelectedCompany.CompanyName}"/>
```

In code behind of the custom control

```
    // Dependency Property
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CompanyNameProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("CompanyName", typeof(string),
         typeof(CompanyDetail), null);

    // .NET Property wrapper
    public string CompanyName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(CompanyNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CompanyNameProperty, value); }
    }
```

There is nothing in the ViewModel. There is the following XAML

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding CompanyName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl, AncestorLevel=1, Mode=FindAncestor}}" />
```

So, when the controls are loaded and shown on screen, I see the value "TestName" in the `TextBox` but, if I change the value by typing and then click an OK button I can see the value has not been updated.

I'm assuming it has nothing to do with INotifyPropertyChanged because I think it's all a reference type any way?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure AncestorLevel=1? You don't need to specify it if you specify AncestorType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CompanyName binding must be made two-way, either by setting it explicitly

```
<local:CompanyDetail
    CompanyName="{Binding SelectedCompany.CompanyName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

or by declaring the dependency property to bind two-way by default

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CompanyNameProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register(
         "CompanyName", typeof(string), typeof(CompanyDetail),
         new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
             null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

Comment: You really are a very intelligent person. This is the second time in as many weeks you have helped. Thank you